# getting header part of pdf document in asp.net from gridview data

Tags: export-to-pdf

// Sys.Application.add_init(function(){$create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid,
{"ClientID":"radAccountSummary","ClientSettings":{"AllowAutoScrollOnDragDrop":true,"EnableRowHoverStyle":true,"ShouldCreateRows":true,"DataBinding":{},"Selecting":{"CellSelectionMode":0,"AllowRowSelect":true},"S
crolling":{},"Resizing":{},"ClientMessages":{},"KeyboardNavigationSettings":{"AllowActiveRowCycle":false,"EnableKeyboardShortcuts":true,"FocusKey":89,"InitInsertKey":73,"RebindKey":82,"ExitEditInsertModeKey":27,"Up
dateInsertItemKey":13,"DeleteActiveRow":127,"ExpandDetailTableKey":39,"CollapseDetailTableKey":37,"SaveChangesKey":85,"CancelChangesKey":67},"Animation":{},"Virtualization":{}},"Skin":"WebBlue","UniqueID":"rad
AccountSummary","_activeRowIndex":"","_controlToFocus":"","_currentPageIndex":0,"_defaultDateTimeFormat":"dd-MM-yyyy
HH:mm:ss","_editIndexes":"[]","_embeddedSkin":true,"_gridTableViewsData":"[{\"ClientID\":\"radAccountSummary_ctl00\",\"UniqueID\":\"radAccountSummary$ctl00\",\"PageSize\":10,\"PageCount\":1,\"EditMode\":\"EditFor
ms\",\"AllowPaging\":false,\"CurrentPageIndex\":0,\"VirtualItemCount\":0,\"AllowMultiColumnSorting\":false,\"AllowNaturalSort\":true,\"AllowFilteringByColumn\":false,\"PageButtonCount\":10,\"HasDetailTables\":false,\"Has
MultiHeaders\":false,\"CheckListWebServicePath\":\"\",\"GroupLoadMode\":\"Server\",\"PagerAlwaysVisible\":false,\"IsItemInserted\":false,\"clientDataKeyNames\":[],\"hasDetailItemTemplate\":false,\"_dataBindTemplates\":f
alse,\"_selectedItemStyle\":\"\",\"_selectedItemStyleClass\":\"rgSelectedRow\",\"_columnsData\":[{\"UniqueName\":\"TransactionDate\",\"Resizable\":true,\"Reorderable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupable\":true,\"ColumnT
ype\":\"GridBoundColumn\",\"ColumnGroupName\":\"\",\"Editable\":true,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\"DataField\":\"TransactionDate\",\"Display\":true},{\"UniqueName\":\"InvoiceNumber\",\"Resizable\":true,\"Reorde
rable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupable\":true,\"ColumnType\":\"GridBoundColumn\",\"ColumnGroupName\":\"\",\"Editable\":true,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\"DataField\":\"InvoiceNumber\",\"Display\":true},{\"Un
iqueName\":\"TranType\",\"Resizable\":true,\"Reorderable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupable\":true,\"ColumnType\":\"GridBoundColumn\",\"ColumnGroupName\":\"\",\"Editable\":true,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\
"DataField\":\"TranType\",\"Display\":true},{\"UniqueName\":\"TransactionDescription\",\"Resizable\":true,\"Reorderable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupable\":true,\"ColumnType\":\"GridBoundColumn\",\"ColumnGroupNam
e\":\"\",\"Editable\":true,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\"DataField\":\"TransactionDescription\",\"Display\":true},{\"UniqueName\":\"TemplateColumn\",\"Resizable\":true,\"Reorderable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupa
ble\":true,\"ColumnType\":\"GridTemplateColumn\",\"ColumnGroupName\":\"\",\"Editable\":false,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\"DataField\":\"TransactionAmount\",\"Display\":true},{\"UniqueName\":\"Total_Fuel\",\"Re
sizable\":true,\"Reorderable\":true,\"Selectable\":true,\"Groupable\":true,\"ColumnType\":\"GridTemplateColumn\",\"ColumnGroupName\":\"\",\"Editable\":false,\"DataTypeName\":\"System.String\",\"DataField\":\"\",\"Display\"
:true}]}]","_masterClientID":"radAccountSummary_ctl00","_shouldFocusOnPage":false,"allowMultiRowSelection":false,"clientStateFieldID":"radAccountSummary_ClientState","expandItems":{}}, null, null,
$get("radAccountSummary"));}); //

Comment: Do not just dump a whole block of code here.  All questions must include an [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: a) Please format this properly as code. b) Please include a description of what's actually wrong here.